# NSUTF8StringEncoding purpose

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Can you please explain me the purpose of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, does it encode the whole data? Can you give an example of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` with an input and output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to tell NSString using which encoding can the bytes of the NSData be interpreted as a valid string. It won't, however, modify/convert your string between encodings. If the NSData object contains a byte sequence which is not valid UTF-8, it will simply return nil.